# Conditionally combine or delete tuples in list

Tags: python, tuples

I have a list of data in Python of the form [(x<sub>0</sub>, f<sub>0</sub>), ..., (x<sub>n</sub>, f<sub>n</sub>)], where the tuple (x<sub>i</sub>, f<sub>i</sub>) represents the location and magnitude, respectively, of the i<sup>th</sup> element. For example:

```py
point_forces = [(0, 4), (3.5, 2), (0, -3.1), (4, 6), (2, 0), (3.5, -4)]
```

What is a good way to remove tuples where f<sub>i</sub> = 0 and combine f<sub>i</sub> + f<sub>j</sub> of tuples where x<sub>i</sub> = x<sub>j</sub>, returning a result in the form [(x<sub>0</sub>, f<sub>0</sub>), ..., (x<sub>m</sub>, f<sub>m</sub>)]? Continuing the example, this is  what I want to get:

```py
result = [(0, 0.9), (3.5, -2), (4, 6)]
```

The order in which these operations are applied or the order in which tuples appear in the resultant list does not matter to me as long as x<sub>i</sub> ≠ x<sub>j</sub> and f<sub>i</sub> ≠ 0 for all i, j in [0, m].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```py
out = {}
for x, f in point_forces:
    if f != 0.0:
        out[x] = out.get(x, 0) + f

out = [(x, round(f, 2)) for x, f in out.items() if f != 0.0]  # if you want to keep the resulting tuples where f=0 then remove the if... part
print(out)
```

Prints:

```py
[(0, 0.9), (3.5, -2), (4, 6)]
```